# Presenting a second UIWindow causes the whole app to become unresponsive (on ios7)

Tags: ios, modal-dialog, uiwindow

So I'm trying to present a "modal view" that still shows the "presenting" view below as you will see in the GIFs below.

I am creating a UIWindow which I simply show over the "main" window. I'm retaining them both in my window manager class and it also does some simple animations.

It works well on the simulator, iOS8 and built with iOS8 SDK. It looks like this:

[image]

But when I open it on my actual device it doesn't work so well. See the GIF below.

[image]

Here's whats happening

1. The first presentation works well, animates the present**er** and shows the modal. User activity is working.
2. The second presentation works 50%. The modal is shown, but the present**er** does not animate. User activity working well.
3. The third presentation does not work at all, at this point the whole app is unresponsive, no taps/buttons/swipes are working

The NSLogs appears to have correct values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

*It appears changing `[presentedWindow makeKeyAndVisible]` to `[presentedWindow setHidden:NO];` is solving my problem. I think I understand why but if someone comes in with a nice explanation I'll mark it as the answer.*

**EDIT** The above was not the solution. It appears that I can present and dismiss it as long as I don't open the keyboard in-between.